# Euler's totient funtion

Tags: number-theory, functions, permutations

Consider a set $ A ={1,2,3,3,4,4,.....,n,n,n,...,n}$ .

Such that every k $ \in A$ occurs exactly $ \phi (k)$ times, where ,$\phi :N \to N$ and it denote number of coprimes before it.

[it is euler's totient funtion]

Consider $N_0 =\phi (1)+......+\phi (n)$. Now consider $a_i$ be permutation of the elements of A $ \forall i={1,2,3,.....,N_0}$

Prove that for all n we must have a permutation so that
$ \sum_{i=1}^{N_0} \frac{1}{a_ia_{i+1}}$ =1 consider$N_0 +1 \to 1$

What I thought:

We will give proof by induction.
Base cases:
$$n=1 \implies \{1,1\}$$$$n=2 \implies \{1,2,1\}$$$$n=3 \implies \{1,3,2,3,1\}$$

First, if you have:-
$$\frac{1}{ab}=\frac{1}{ax}+\frac{1}{xb} \implies \frac{1}{ab}=\frac{a+b}{xab} \implies x=a+b$$

Comment: What do "consider$N_0+1\to 1$" and the sequences $\{1,1\},\{1,2,1\},\{1,3,2,3,1\}$ mean? I have no idea about the first one and the sequences in the second one are not proper permutations solving your problem. Could you fix all the typoes and describe the problem clearly? Also, is $a_{i+1} =: a_1$ when $i=N_0$?

Comment: @KanuKim I do not know correctly what errors, got the problem ready